# Problema de ruta al subir a un host compartido. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, hosting

Tengo un proyecto **Laravel** que lo he subido a un host compartido siguiendo los pasos de esta pagina: [https://www.nigmacode.com/laravel/Subir-proyecto-laravel-a-hosting#:~:text=Subir%20nuestro%20proyecto%20laravel%20a,donde%20arrastremos%20nuestro%20archivo%20zip](https://www.nigmacode.com/laravel/Subir-proyecto-laravel-a-hosting#:%7E:text=Subir%20nuestro%20proyecto%20laravel%20a,donde%20arrastremos%20nuestro%20archivo%20zip).

Pero me muestra un error donde dice:

`"file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\zll\pruebas\laravel\prueba\storage\framework/sessions/aMaMNHB8PNqFxMFrxB1IE6s8XB7nblxTMO9nwY7N): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ◀"`

que esa ruta se supone que es la ruta del sitio local.

¿Como configuro esto?

Comment: No tengo la shell, necesito hacerlo manualmente

Comment: El problema es que dejaste la ruta de tu proyecto local `C:\xampp\...`, deberías cambiarla por la ruta del servidor, algo como: `/home/usuario/public_html/...`

Comment: Como lo cambio? en que archivo

Comment: No tengo la menor idea, desconozco _Laravel_, pero debe haber un script donde defines las rutas y es ahí donde debes modificarlo.

Comment: Vale, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Limpia las caches, bien justo antes de subir el proyecto con los comando de artisan, o manualmente eliminando el contenido de los directorios de cache. En `bootstrap/cache`, `storage/framework/cache/data` y quizás también alguno de los de vistas